# I restart the server when the file is changed in express,but npm run devstart error

Tags: node.js, windows, express

{
"name": "myapp",
"version": "0.0.0",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"start": "node  ./bin/www",
"devstart": "nodemon ./bin/www"
},
"dependencies": {
"cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
"debug": "~2.6.9",
"express": "^4.19.1",
"http-errors": "~1.6.3",
"jade": "^0.31.2",
"morgan": "~1.9.1"
}
}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2i0Ys.png)

I modified package.json,add `"scripts":{"devstart": "nodemon ./bin/www"}` but when I run a Windows terminal，type in `npm run devstart` ，terminal display error. I created a new file
nodemon。json

```json
{
    "restarable":"rs",
    "ignore":[
        ".git",
        ".svn",
        "node_modules/**/node_modules"
    ],
    "verbose": true,
    "execMap":{
        "js":"node --harmony"
    },
    "watch":[
        
    ],
    "env":{
        "NODE_ENV":"development"
    },
    "exit":"js json njk css js"
}
```

but no use

Comment: The error says you _didn't_ add "devstart" as a script in your `package.json`, so replace the JSON you're showing atm (which is unrelated to the problem) with your actual `package.json` content. That said: [do not show images of text](/help/how-to-ask): copy-paste the text, and put it in code formatting.